# Batch processing with reactive Couchbase java driver

Tags: reactive-programming, couchbase

Suppose I have a bucket from which I need to fetch documents that have a date older than now.
This document looks like this:

```
{
id: "1",
date: "Some date",
otherObjectKEY: "key1"
}
```

For each document, I need to fetch another document using its **otherObjectKEY**, send the latter to a kafka topic, then delete the original document.

Using the **reactive java driver 3.0**, I was able to do it with something like this:

```
public void batch(){
    streamOriginalObjects()
         .flatMap(originalObject -> fetchOtherObjectUsingItsKEY(originalObject)
                       .flatMap(otherObject -> sendToKafkaAndDeleteOriginalObject(originalObject))
         )
         .subscribe();
}
```

**streamOriginalObjects():**

```
public Flux<OriginalObject> streamOriginalObjects(){
        return client.query("select ... and date <= '"+ LocalDateTime.now().toString() +"'")
                .flux()
                .flatMap(result -> result.rowsAs(OriginalObject.class));
    }
```

It works like expected, but I'm wondering if there is a better approach (especially in terms of performance) than streaming and processing element by element.

Answer (score 2):

Doing a N1QL query, and then fanning-out key-value operations from that, is a useful and common pattern.  This should make the fan-out happen in parallel:

```
    streamOriginalObjects()
        // Split into numberOfThreads 'rails'
        .parallel(numberOfThreads)

        // Run on an unlimited thread pool
        .runOn(Schedulers.elastic())

        .concatMap(originalObject -> fetchOtherObjectUsingItsKEY(originalObject)
            .concatMap(otherObject -> sendToKafkaAndDeleteOriginalObject(originalObject))
        )

        // Back out of parallel mode
        .sequential()
        .subscribe();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a particular reason here to use concatMap instead of flatMap?

Comment: @Monta I default to either using concatMap for serial ops or parallel+concatMap for parallel ops.  flatMap can bring its own concurrency in, which confuses things.